# Most general nonlinear Lorentz transformation law can be built from linear transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, representation-theory, non-linear-systems

Peskin and Schroeder give a Lorentz transformation law:
$$\Phi_a(x)\rightarrow M_{ab}(\Lambda)\Phi_b(\Lambda^{-1}x).\tag{3.8}$$

Then they say that

> "the most general nonlinear [Lorentz] transformation law can be built from these linear transformations".

What does this mean? They don't elaborate on it, but they say "it can be shown" (without giving a reference).

Comment: Repeat by restricting to rotations. Are you *completely* comfortable with that?